# how to visit certain screen of native ios app using appium and selenium-webdriver

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, appium

I'm writing automated tests in cucumber for native ios app using appium and webdriver, and I've faced a problem with going to certain screen.

For example: I have "edit profile" screen, which can be reached from "profile" screen, which can be reached from screen where app starts.

I have some tests to do on that page, so I want to write precondition like: "I'm on "edit profile" tab",
to skip steps of reaching that screen.
I've tried to use:

```
@page=selenium.find_element(:id,'Edit profile') #where "Edit profile" is XCode acessability ID
selenium.navigate().to(page)
```

But it doesn't work.

Would be great if someone has any suggestions on this,

Thanks, stay awesome)

Comment: Are you directly trying to reach that screen without clicking on `Profile`? I guess you need to have a precondition look like? `@page=selenium.find_element(:id,'Edit profile').click` ? and then assert on that page?

Comment: This line doesn't work, and it actually can't because i simply don't have element with that id on a first screen

Comment: You have to use `deep link` and launch that particular activity in the application to reach directly to that section. Mention, what activity you want to launch to the appium by using the unique `launch activity` name